# How to filter a chart by a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with something easy that I can't make it work (I'm a beginner). I have a dataframe and want to plot a simple chart: the x-axis should display periods and the y-axis should display sales. Now I want the chart to show only a specific range of years, not all of them.

So far I've tried the following:

```
df.plot(x="Period", y="Quantity", kind="line")
```

But I don't know how to narrow it down to specific values within that column, e.g. `x="Period"` should be greater than 2018?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df['Period']` is of type int, then you can filter the data that is sent to the plot using `df[df['Period] >= 1990]`.

Your updated code would be...

```
df[df['Period']>=1990].plot(x="Period", y="Quantity", kind="line")
```

For sake of completeness, if the period column is of type datetime, then you can use pandas `pd.DatetimeIndex().year` to get the year as int and filter for all years >=1990, like this...

```
df[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Period']).year>=1990].plot(x="Period", y="Quantity", kind="line")
```